# Gaussian probability distribution for a delta correlated variable

Tags: physics, stochastic-calculus

I read in a paper that I have a vector $\bf{x}$ such that

$$
          \langle x_i (t) x_j (t')\rangle=\delta_{ij}\delta(t-t')
   $$
    and the probability distribution for $\bf{x(t)}$ is a Gaussian distribution and it can be written as:
        $$
\exp\left[-\int_0^T\,\mathrm dt \sum_{i,j} A^{i,j}x_i(t)x_j(t)\right]
$$
    where $A^{i,j}$ is the variance matrix. Can someone please help how this Gaussian distribution is written; especially why there is an integral in the exponent.

Comment: What is the problem, where is the question? Do you want to write this in code?

Comment: the question is how this distribution is written? Generally there is no integral sign in the exponent in the expression of Gaussian distribution. I don't understand from where this intergal between 0 to T comes. If you can help with this, many thanks.